# UICollectionview Sections/Rows/Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to do something with an UICollectionView. I want them centered in the middle, but therefor i need to create something like this:

```
(Array consists of 5 items)
X X <- 2 items in section 1
X X <- 2 items in section 2
X   <- 1 item in section 3
```

But the problem is that the items doesn't show up right? If i would have 3 items. The items would be like, In section 1, item 1 and 2. and then in section 2 would be item 1 again, instead if item 3 of my array.

This is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    float uitkomst = ceilf((float)[arrayDobbel count] / 2) - 1; // Array starts at 0 so need to do - 1

    if (uitkomst == section) {
        return 1; // Last cell
    }
    return 2; //Always 2 cells to each other, not the last section
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    float uitkomst = ceilf((float)[arrayDobbel count] / 2); //Calculate how much sections. Always 2 items / section

    return (int)uitkomst;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    detailDice *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"dobbelsteenGame" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
    cell.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.188 green:0.341 blue:0.612 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    [[cell detaildiceLabel] setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[arrayDobbel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] returnRandomOptie]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Could anyone help me with the display of the right texts in the right cells?

Kind Regards

Comment: You play with `section` and `row` and `section`isn't used in your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    ....
    //since there is 2 items in each section
    int index = 2*indexPath.section + indexPath.row;
    [[cell detaildiceLabel] setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[arrayDobbel objectAtIndex:index] returnRandomOptie]]];

    return cell;
}
```